# Prove that "$|X|\leq|Y|$" is a $\Sigma_1$ formula. (Minor question in the solution)

Tags: logic, set-theory

This is exercise $13.13$ in Jech's "Set Theory" 3rd edition. We wish to show that "$|X|\leq|Y|$" is a $\Sigma_1$ formula. This feels very obvious. Write it as a formula, i.e. "$\exists f$ from $X$ into $Y$." Here's my doubt. I can intuitively see that the rest of the sentence "from $X$ into $Y$" is $\Delta_0$, in other words it doesn't contain unbounded quantifiers. However, I'm not exactly sure how to $prove$ that. Perhaps I don't know enough logic to be able to describe a function, and moreso injectivity strictly using $\land,\lor,\neg,\iff,\implies$. $f(x) = f(y)\implies x=y$ is not enough, as we want to further decompose $f(x)$ into its logical components. Could someone help me with this doubt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First write down $\varphi(X,Y,f)$ stating that:

1. $f$ is a function.
2. $\operatorname{dom}(f)=X$.
3. $\operatorname{rng}(f)\subseteq Y$.
4. $f$ is injective.

These are all $\Delta_0$ statements, since they involve quantifying over elements of $f$ or elements of $X$ or elements of $Y$, which are given as free variables. You can either write it out explicitly or rely on what is implicit in the proofs that appear in the chapter earlier.

Now $|X|\leq|Y|$ is simply $\exists f\varphi(X,Y,f)$. So it is $\Sigma_1$ by definition.